# Count unique different values partitioned by given column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert this input table:

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ conversationId ║ LengthOfCOnversation ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║              1 ║                    1 ║
║              1 ║                    2 ║
║              1 ║                    2 ║
║              1 ║                    5 ║
║              1 ║                    5 ║
║              1 ║                    5 ║
║              1 ║                    5 ║
║              1 ║                    5 ║
║              1 ║                    1 ║
║              1 ║                    3 ║
║              1 ║                    3 ║
║              1 ║                    3 ║
║              2 ║                    1 ║
║              2 ║                    2 ║
║              2 ║                    2 ║
║              3 ║                    2 ║
║              3 ║                    2 ║
║              4 ║                    1 ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

to the following output in sql:

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ conversationId ║ LengthOfCOnversation ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║              1 ║                    1 ║
║              1 ║                    2 ║
║              1 ║                    5 ║
║              1 ║                    1 ║
║              1 ║                    3 ║
║              2 ║                    1 ║
║              2 ║                    2 ║
║              3 ║                    2 ║
║              4 ║                    1 ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

We are trying to group the same `LengthOfConversation` in the input to one per `conversationId`.

Comment: Do you have an order column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i've edited this :), hope you will help

Comment: @Zhorov, no but i can add any column that would help

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Without a column to determine the order of the rows, there's simply no reliable way to do what you want, because database tables are unsorted. For more information, read my blog post [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Answer (score 2):

You need a column to determine the order of the rows and if I understand the question correctly, the following approach is one possible solution. Note, that in the example the `Id` column determines the order of the rows.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id int IDENTITY(1, 1),
   ConversationId int,
   LenOfConversation int
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (ConversationId, LenOfConversation)
VALUES
   (1, 1),
   (1, 2),
   (1, 2),
   (1, 5),
   (1, 5),
   (1, 5),
   (1, 5),
   (1, 5),
   (1, 1),
   (1, 3),
   (1, 3),
   (1, 3),
   (1, 3),
   (1, 2)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   ConversationId, LenOfConversation
FROM (   
   SELECT
      Id,
      ConversationId,
      LenOfConversation,
      LAG(LenOfConversation) OVER (PARTITION BY ConversationId ORDER BY Id) AS LenOfConversation_Prev
   FROM Data
) t
WHERE (LenOfConversation_Prev IS NULL) OR (LenOfConversation <> LenOfConversation_Prev)
ORDER BY Id
```

Result:

```
ConversationId  LenOfConversation
1               1
1               2
1               5
1               1
1               3
1               2
```